# Why using loops in recursion produce an unexpected results?

Tags: c++, recursion

I have the following function.

```
int n,cnt,i,j;
int a[100];
void can(int x,int c){
    if (x == 0){
        for (i = 0; i < c; i++){
            cout << a[i];
        } cout<<endl;
    }
    if (x<0) c-=1;
    else{
        a[c] = 1;
        can(x-1,c+1);
        a[c] = 2;
        can(x-2,c+1);
    }
}
int main(){
    cin >> n;
    can(n,0);
}
```

I want to cut a rope length n into length 1 or length 2 and print all of the possible cut.
Such as

**Input:** 4 will produce
**Output:** 1111
112
121
211
22

The code above works, but when I replace the code in the else section using the code below, why does it not produce the same output?

```
for (j = 1;j <= 2; j++){
      a[c] = j;
      can(x-j,c+1);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it's a recursive function, but `j` is global, so you only have 1 `j`. That's why this loop here:

```
for (j = 1;j <= 2; j++){
      a[c] = j;
      can(x-j,c+1);
}
```

Produces bad results, because the same `j` is used multiple times despite this not being your intention. Try this instead:

```
for (int j = 1;j <= 2; j++){
      a[c] = j;
      can(x-j,c+1);
}
```

Now each execution of the loop has its own `j`, so it should work as intended.